# Doesn't JVM need all the interface methods to be implemented?

Tags: java, grails, groovy

I am trying groovy , so i write a sample HelloWorld Program in groovy and compiled it & run it works fine, when  i saw the compiled code using JAD decompiler my HelloWorld program implements a GroovyObject interface but it doesn't implemented all the methods in that interface , so it means only java compiler forces us to implemented all the method in interface but JVM does not need that. Am i right?

This is decompiled groovy code :

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.lang.MetaClass;
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSite;

public class Helloworld_1   implements GroovyObject {
  public Helloworld_1()  {
    Helloworld_1 this;
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite = $getCallSiteArray();
    MetaClass localMetaClass = $getStaticMetaClass();
    this.metaClass = localMetaClass;  }

  public static void main(String... args){
    CallSite[] arrayOfCallSite =  $getCallSiteArray();
    arrayOfCallSite[0].callStatic(Helloworld_1.class, "Hello World");
  }  
 static {}
}
```

Any one please help....

Comment: I think this would be better if split in two questions

Comment: Yep I Splitted into two.

Comment: `$getCallSiteArray()` also isn't declared.

Comment: The code I posted above is decompiled code[I used JAD decompiler]

Comment: I tried deocmpiling using jd-gui. Got a similar result, with a few undeclared methods being called. Maybe groovy use proxies to add the functionality.

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with your decompiler?

Answer (score 1):

I can see the implementation of `GroovyObject` when using Groovy Console.  To display the generated source code, I select *Script*, *Inspect Ast*, and choose *Class Generation* for *At end of Phase*.  I can also see the generated bytecode by selecting *Bytecode* tab.

I believe the source code that is responsible for implementing `GroovyObject` methods is in `org.codehaus.groovy.classgen.Verifier`.  There is a method named `addGroovyObjectInterfaceAndMethods()`.  You can find the source code in https://github.com/groovy/groovy-core/blob/master/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/classgen/Verifier.java#L310.

Comment: Thanks for you answer . I saw the AST transformation in groovy console but AST transformation occurs at compile time so how come our compiled code works in JVM?

Comment: When compiling the source, Groovy uses ASM library to generate methods (including the implementation of `GroovyObject`). The generated class should be a valid JVM class.  I haven't use JAD before.  Try to use `javap` tool from JDK, such as `javap -p -c MyClass`, you will see all methods from the interface are exists.